# Global variables in Controller class are overridden with latest session opened

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have developed an application using spring-MVC and hibernate, which is having signup page . When user tries to  signup , application sends an OTP to user mail and I have maintained this OTP sent by the application in controller class as global variable. So, here the problem is when two users are accessing at a time latest requested user otp is overriding the old one and because of this first user is unable to signup.

1 > Does spring maintain separate session for each user accessing the application? If no ?how to solve this problem?.

Please find below code.

controller class:

```
package com.uday;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class ControllerSignUp_Login {

    private final Login_DetailsDao dao;
    private Login_Details ld = new Login_Details();
    private String OtpMailed = "";
    private MailSendTest mailSender;
    private int chances = 4;
    private String emailAdd;

    public ControllerSignUp_Login(Login_DetailsDao login_DetailsDao, MailSendTest mailSender) {
        this.dao = login_DetailsDao;
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @Transactional
    public String diaplay(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("pass") String pass, Model m) {
        if (dao.isLogoinSuccessfull(name, pass)) {
            m.addAttribute("message", "Hello " + name + " You are successfully logged in");
            return "Success";
        } else {
            m.addAttribute("message", "Cannot validate given details.Please try again");
            return "login";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/SignUp")
    public String redirect() {
        System.out.println("ControllerSignUp_Login.display()");
        chances = 4;
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String display() {
        System.out.println("ControllerSignUp_Login.display()");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/updateDetails")
    @Transactional
    public String display(HttpServletRequest req, Model M) {
        String firstName = req.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = req.getParameter("lastName");
        String mobileNo = req.getParameter("mobileNo");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        if (checkLength(firstName) && checkLength(lastName) && checkLength(mobileNo) && checkLength(address)
                && checkLength(email) && checkLength(password)) {

            ld.setFirstName(firstName);
            ld.setLastName(lastName);
            ld.setEmail(email);
            ld.setAddress(address);
            ld.setMobileNo(mobileNo);
            ld.setPassword(password);
            if (dao.validateMobileAndEmail(mobileNo, email)) {
                doSendEmail(email);
                M.addAttribute("cMessage", false);
                return "ValidationPage";
            } else {
                M.addAttribute("message", "MobileNo/Email is already registered");
                return "signup";
            }

        } else {
            M.addAttribute("message", "SignUp Failed !! All details are mandatory.");
            return "signup";

        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Home")
    public String displayy() {
        return "Home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String display1() {
        return "login";
    }

    public boolean checkLength(String s) {
        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping("/submitToDB")
    public String submitToDataBase(HttpServletRequest req, Model M) {

        String otp = req.getParameter("otp");
        System.out.println("ControllerSignUp_Login.submitToDataBase()" + otp);
        if (OtpMailed.equals(otp)) {
            dao.saveEmployee(ld);
            chances = 4;
            M.addAttribute("message", "SignUp Successfull !! Thank You");
            M.addAttribute("displayLogin", true);
            return "Success";
        } else {
            if (chances != 1) {
                chances = chances - 1;
                M.addAttribute("message", chances + " Chances Left");
                return "ValidationPage";
            } else {
                chances = 4;
                M.addAttribute("message", "Authorization failed");
                return "signup";
            }

        }

    }

    @RequestMapping("/validate")
    public String validateOtp() {
        return "Success";
    }

    public String generateOtp() {
        String otp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Double d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
            int value = d.intValue();
            if (value == 10) {
                otp = otp + 1;
            } else {
                otp = otp + value;
            }
        }
        return otp;

    }

    public void doSendEmail(String mail) {
        try {
            this.emailAdd = mail;
            String recipientAddress = mail;
            String subject = "One Time Verification <Uday>";
            String otpGenerated = generateOtp();
            this.OtpMailed = otpGenerated;
            String message = "Please use this OTP " + otpGenerated + "  to signup. ";
            mailSender.Send("xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "lxrxnxnhmyclvzxs", recipientAddress, subject, message);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping("/resend")
    public String resend(Model m) {
        doSendEmail(this.emailAdd);
        m.addAttribute("message", chances + " Chances Left");
        return "ValidationPage";
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to make all fields in a service final to avoid exactly this type of situation. Search for "Spring MVC HTTP session" and you will find plenty of documentation. Finally, this is fine for learning, but don't write your own security code like this for real applications--use Spring Security instead.

Comment: @chrylis I have done it by storing those values in HttpSession Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Spring REST Controllers are always scoped as singletons (`@Controller` annotation implies that). You're **NOT** supposed to re-use private class level variables/fields on method invocation.

If you have global concerns you need to manage/visit outside the scope of a single request, please be sure to separate them to different classes.

Otherwise, the entire modification scope that takes place inside `@RequestMapping` annotated methods should be method/function-local.